# Backbone View - not finding the $el, after Model triggers

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-model

I am doing a simple validation for my username and password. My Model is here:

```
define(["backbone"], function(Backbone){
    var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'/home',
        defaults:{
                userName:'',
                password:''
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.bind("change", this.attributesChanged);
        },
        validate:function(attrs){

            var errors = [];
            if(attrs.userName < 5){
                 errors.push({"name": 'userName', "message": 'Please fill email field.'});
            }
            if(!attrs.password){
                errors.push({"name": 'password', "message": 'Please fill feedback field.'});
            }
            return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
        },
        attributesChanged : function(){
            var valid = false;
            if (this.get('userName') && this.get('password')) {
                valid = true;
                this.trigger("validated", valid);
            }           
            else {
                this.trigger('invalid', valid); //triggers the invalid works fine.
            }
        }

        });

    return LoginModel;
});
```

But in the view, I am still getting that trigger, but I am not able to get the view's element to highlight the inputs:

here is my view:

```
define([
    'jQuery','underscore',
    'backbone','marionette',
    'text!./templates/loginView.html'],
    function($,_,Backbone,Marionette,template){
        "use strict";

        var LoginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            className:'col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4',

            template:_.template(template),

            events:{
                "submit form" : "loginSubmit"
            },

            initialize:function(params){
                this.model.view = this;
                this.model.bind("validated", this.validated);
                this.model.bind("invalid", this.showErrors);
            },

            loginSubmit:function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                var form = e.target,
                    data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(form);

                var that = this;

                var options = {
                    success: function (model,response) {
                        if(response){
                            console.log('success', response)
                        } else {
                            console.log('failed')
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(model, options){
                        console.log("error", xhr.responseText);
                    }
                };

                this.model.save(data, options);
                // this.model.on('invalid', function(model, error) { console.log(model,'\n', error); })
            },

            validated:function(value){
                console.log(value);
            },

            showErrors:function(model, error){
                var form = this.$el.find('form'); // i am not able to get form element here... what is the issue?
                _.each(error, function(value, key){
                    var input = form.find('input[name='+value.name+']').addClass('error');
                    input.after('<span class="errorMsg">'+value.message+'</span>');
                });
            },

            hideErrors:function(msg){
                console.log('login success!');
            },

            onShow:function(){
                $('input:text').first().select();
            }

        });

        return LoginView;
    }
);
```

And I am confused in this parts, any help me to uderstand:

1) How to differenciate whether the error from 'validate' method or 'server'

2) How to handle this both properly?

3) what is the correct approach that, what i posted here?

I am not so experienced in this areas, any expert can help me to proceed my app dev?

don't direct my to some books, i came across please help me to learn from my code.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer your questions below:

1. the `invalid` event is triggered from `validate` (which you may want to consider using since you can validate on `set` of properties). the `error` event is triggered when the response comes from the server.
2. `validate` will not send information to the server. You should use that if that's the response you're looking for.
3. What you have is pretty good.

---

Here's how to fix your reference problem:

Instead of this in your view's `initialize`:

```
initialize:function(params){
  this.model.view = this;
  this.model.bind("validated", this.validated);
  this.model.bind("invalid", this.showErrors);
}
```

You should do:

```
initialize:function(params){
  this.model.view = this;
  this.listenTo(this.model, "validated", this.validated);
  this.listenTo(this.model, "invalid", this.showErrors);
}
```

which ensures that when the view is closed, the events will be removed. It also makes sure that the `this` in your methods refers to your view. Right now, it refers to your model.

Also, just an aside, if you want to `find` a selector within your view, there's a shortcut – `this.$` – which is the same as `this.$el.find`.